# c# сделать первую букву заглавной

Tags: c#, winforms

Сложно ли сделать проверку заглавная ли первая буква содержимого xml тегов `<t2>` (содержимое тегов может быть из нескольких слов) и если нет, то сделать заглавной?

```
   <tag>
    <tag1>    </tag1>
    <tag2>    </tag2>
    <root>
    <ttt><t1></t1><t2></t2></ttt>
    <ttt><t1></t1><t2></t2><t3></t3></ttt>
    <ttt><t1></t1><t2></t2><t3></t3><t4></t4></ttt>
    </root>
   </tag>
```

Comment: Добавьте код который уже есть. Сделать не сложно но нужно понимать как у вас хранится XML, как вы из него извлекаете элементы и на основе каких (надеюсь стандартных) классов вы с ним работаете. Без этого ответить на ваш вопрос можно только так, как я уже ответил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для XDocument и приведенного примера можно например так:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"SomeFile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
    from el in doc.Descendants("ttt")
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in elements)
{
    StringBuilder elementText  = new StringBuilder(el.Element("t2").Value);
    if (Char.IsLower(elementText[0]))
    {
        elementText[0] = Char.ToUpper(elementText[0]);
    }
    el.Element("t2").Value = elementText.ToString();
    elementText.Clear();
}  
doc.Save(@"SomeFile.xml");
```

Больше подробностей и возможностей описано в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), на русском языке и даже почти без ошибок машинного перевода.

Comment: а зачем делать проверку на Lower?

Comment: чтобы не делать лишнюю работу, вряд ли проверяться будет только один тег

Comment: Извиняюсь, это проверка на заглавную букву названия тега или содержимого тега? Просто нужно содержимое

Comment: @Андрей название тега вы получить можете? если нет, тогда сейчас дополню

Comment: @Андрей так все таки содержимое или имя тега?

Comment: Содержимое. Название тега думаю без разницы с какой буквы, а содержимое неприятно что с маленькой

Comment: @Андрей добавьте в вопрос фрагмент кода, чтобы было понятно какие именно классы вы используете для работы с XML, там есть варианты, от этого зависит ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36436/discussion-between-rdorn-and-).

Comment: А как цикл добавить в код, помогите, а?

Comment: Какой именно? для чего? По правде говоря если у вас проблема с добавлением кода в цикл, то лучше все таки почитать про язык и его синтаксис и базовые конструкции. Извините, но это необходимый минимум. Тут да же отдельный вопрос есть посвященный литературе по C# и .NET

Comment: @Андрей по поставленному вопросу ответ больше дополнить нечем. Подробностей решаемой задачи нет, минимального кода чтобы понять окружение в котором необходимо найти решение нет. Поди туда, не знаю куда. Добавьте необходимый минимум в вопрос.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Андрей дополнил ответ

Comment: А как бы сократить код до указания тега `<ttt>` и `<t2>`? а то у меня ошибки выдает, да и указывать всю структуру документа не нужно

Comment: @Андрей Например так. а по поводу ошибок... покажите код, мои способности к телепатии весьма скромны. У меня работает, я непроверенный код не выкладываю

Comment: ДА-ДА-дА. Нет слов, все работает!!!!!!! Спасибо огромное!! Отличный код!

Answer (score 3):

Вот так должно сработать:

```
string slovo = "zaglavnaya";

slovo = char.ToUpper(slovo[0]) + slovo.Substring(1);
```

Comment: А применительно к тегам как?

Comment: @Андрей зависимо от того как вы их обрабатываете. Приведите в вопросе конкретный код обработки XML и тогда можно будет дать более конкретный ответ

Comment: так не сработает, строка C# неизменяема, т.е. в ней нельза заменить один символ.

Comment: @rdorn точно, сейчас поправлю. спасибо